# Permutations of x options in y places

Tags: javascript, arrays, permutation

This seems similar to other permutation questions but the differences are proving to be a challenge.

`given x options`  (generally 3-7,  or  `[a,b,c]` to `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]` )

get all `permutations of y length` (also generally 3-7)

```
x = [a,b,c]  y = 7 

[a,a,a,a,a,a,a]
[a,a,a,a,a,a,b]
[a,a,a,a,a,b,a]
[a,a,a,a,b,a,c]
[a,c,a,b,a,a,a]
     etc.
```

or

```
x=7 [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]    y=3

[a,a,a]
[a,d,g]
[a,g,d]
[g,d,a]
  etc.
```

I'd like to say I've gotten somewhere but I don't even know how to start this, and every other solution involving permutations seems to rely heavily on string length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not really permutations, they are strings over an alphabet. It can be implemented recursively like this:

```js
let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let strings = [];

function generateStrings(alphabet, strings, length, prefix = []) 
{
  for (let letter of alphabet) {
    if (length === 1) {
      strings.push([letter].concat(prefix));
    } else {
      generateStrings(alphabet, strings, length - 1, [letter].concat(prefix));
    }
  }
}

generateStrings(alphabet, strings, 3);

console.log(strings);
```

Hope this helps.